# Is there a way to only show a div when a user is scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so a div is only displayed when a user scrolls. When they stop scrolling the div fades out.

I've googled various terms but perhaps my terms aren't right as the results returning are about showing a div at a certain height.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `onscroll` event to show the div and set a timer to fade it.

Comment: Duh! Didn't think to check for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery's `.scroll` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
var myTimeout = -1;                    // Var to store a timeout reference in
$(window).scroll(function() {          // When the user scrolls the window
    $('#myDiv').show();                // Show the div (Any element)
    if(myTimeout !== -1){              // If a timeout is running
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);       // Clear that timeout
    }
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ // Set a timeout to hide the div
        $('#myDiv').hide();            // Function that hides the div
    }, 1000);                          // Run the function after 1 sec (1000 ms)
});
```

This piece of code shows the div when the user starts scrolling, then hides it 1 second after the user stops scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

via jQuery Mobile

```
$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
  alert("Stopped scrolling!");
});


 $(document).on("scrollstart",function(){
  alert("Started scrolling!");
});
```

Comment: `scrollstart` and `scrollstop` are available in jQuery Mobile only.